# Lambdas, callable class instances, and scoping; why doesn't it work in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, lambda, python-2.7, scope

Can someone explain to me why the following code produces the exception it does?

```
>>> class CallableKlass(object):
    def __init__(self, callible):
        self.callible = callible
    def __call__(self, arg):
        return self.callible(arg)


>>> class Klass(object):
    d = {'foo': 'bar'}
    m = CallableKlass(lambda x: d[x])


>>> Klass.m('foo')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    Klass.m('foo')
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 5, in __call__
    return self.callible(arg)
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 3, in <lambda>
    m = CallableKlass(lambda x: d[x])
NameError: global name 'd' is not defined
```

Comment: I believe it's `Class` and not a `Klass`.

Comment: @iTayb I think the OP just wanted to avoid keyword conflicts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class namespace (stuff defined directly in the class body) is not accessible from within functions defined in that namespace.  A lambda is just a function, so this applies to lambdas as well.  Your `CallableKlass` is a red herring.  The behavior is the same in this simpler case:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     d = {'foo': 'bar'}
...     (lambda stuff: d[stuff])('foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    class Foo(object):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 3, in Foo
    (lambda stuff: d[stuff])('foo')
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 3, in <lambda>
    (lambda stuff: d[stuff])('foo')
NameError: global name 'd' is not defined
>>> class Foo(object):
...     d = {'foo': 'bar'}
...     def f(stuff):
...         d[stuff]
...     f('foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    class Foo(object):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 5, in Foo
    f('foo')
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 4, in f
    d[stuff]
NameError: global name 'd' is not defined
```

Comment: +1. Do you know why Python chooses to exhibit this behaviour? It seems at odds with its normal closure rules - cf functions defined in functions

Comment: @poorsod: I'm not totally sure, but I think it's to avoid method names shadowing global functions.  If class-level attributes were in scope for subsequent methods, and you wrote a class that contained a `sum` method, say, then all methods defined after that in the class block would no longer have access to the builtin `sum` function (they'd be reading the just-defined method instead).

Answer (score 2):

you should use `Klass.d` inside lambda, as the variables declared inside a class becomes attribute of that class.
That's why your program raised that error, as it is not able to find anything like `d` in global variables.:

```
class Klass(object):
    d = {'foo': 'bar'}
    m = CallableKlass(lambda x: Klass.d[x])
```